# Analyse data with degree of affection

Tags: data-analysis, categorical-data

[image]

Hello everyone! I'm a newbie studying Data Analysis.
If you'd like to see relationship how A,B,C affects outcome, you may use several models such as KNN, SVM, Logistics regression (as far as I know).

But all of them are kinda *categorical*, rather than *degree of affection*.

Let's say, I'd like to show how Fonts and Colors contribute the degree of attraction (as shown).
What models can I use?

Thousands thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your input is only categorical variables (and having a few values each), then there are finitely many potential samples. Therefore, the model will have finitely many inputs, and, therefore, only a few outputs. Just warning.

If you use, say, KNN or random forest, you can assign L2 norm as your accuracy metric. It will emphasize that 1 is closer to 2 than 5 (pls don't forget to normalize).